# Flutter XCode-build error Could not build module 'firebase_core'

Tags: xcode, firebase, flutter, flutter-dependencies, xcodebuild

Encountered the following error while building the app for IOS:

```
Xcode's output:
↳
    While building module 'firebase_core' imported from /Users/amishra19/Library/Android/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-2.1.0/ios/Classes/FLTQuerySnapshotStreamHandler.m:6:
    In file included from <module-includes>:1:
    In file included from /Users/amishra19/Documents/Projects/Apps/Mingo/Mingo_Flutter_App/mingo_application/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/firebase_core/firebase_core-umbrella.h:13:
    In file included from /Users/amishra19/Library/Android/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.1.1/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.h:11:
    /Users/amishra19/Library/Android/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.1.1/ios/Classes/FLTFirebasePlugin.h:9:9: error: include of non-modular header inside framework module 'firebase_core.FLTFirebasePlugin': '/Users/amishra19/Documents/Projects/Apps/Mingo/Mingo_Flutter_App/mingo_application/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' [-Werror,-Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module]
    #import <FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h>
            ^
    1 error generated.
    /Users/amishra19/Library/Android/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-2.1.0/ios/Classes/FLTQuerySnapshotStreamHandler.m:6:9: fatal error: could not build module 'firebase_core'
    #import <firebase_core/FLTFirebasePluginRegistry.h>
     ~~~~~~~^


This are the dependencies
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  provider: ^4.0.0
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  intl: ^0.17.0
  http: ^0.13.3
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+1
  flag: ^3.2.2
  device_info: ^2.0.0
  firebase_storage: ^8.0.6
  firebase_database: ^6.1.2
  firebase_core: ^1.0.0
  firebase_auth: ^1.1.4
  cloud_firestore: ^2.0.0
  flutter_easyloading: ^3.0.0
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score -3):

update your firebase_core package with latest version,
then  use following command your ios directory terminal

1. rm Podfile.lock
2. rm Podfile
3. pod deintegrate; pod install `remove DerivedData` Folder in xcode.